# irql_not_less_or_equal Disable BIOS Memory options STOP: 0x0000000A (0xF000E987, 0x00000002, 0x00000001, 0x808247A4)

Tags: windows, windows-xp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [irql_not_less_or_equal Disable BIOS Memory options STOP: 0x0000000A (0xF000E987, 0x00000002, 0x00000001, 0x808247A4)](https://superuser.com/questions/539498/irql-not-less-or-equal-disable-bios-memory-options-stop-0x0000000a-0xf000e987)

My exact Problem is:

> When i Switch on the PC and system boots/starts with Windows XP
>   Professional OS, i'm able to see the windows XP logo and with progress
>   bar processing  but after the logo and processing i'm not getting the
>   'WELCOME or LOGIN prompt PAGE/screen' immediately my PC is getting
>   restarted automatically. I mean to say this problem is occurring
>   continuously.
>
> PC On -> Windows XP logo processing screen -> Auto Restarting the PC
>   -> Windows Xp logo processing screen -> Automatically restart

What i tried:

> With Windows XP bootable CD first i tried either Repair option then
>   with Fresh installation also.... I'm unable to perform Repair or fresh
>   installation of Windows XP Professional too. As soon as i select the
>   Repair or Fresh installation option i'm getting the Blue screen as
>   below.

I'm getting a blue screen with the following information.

BLUE screen information:

```
"A problem has been detected and Windows has been Shutdown to prevent Damage to your computer IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL
....
...
...
....

Disable BIOS Memory options such as Caching or Shadowing.
....
....
....

STOP: 0x0000000A (0xF000E987, 0x00000002, 0x00000001, 0x808247A4)"
```

I would request if anyone could help me with proper resolution and suitable solution other than Formatting/Clean installation option for the same.

**As i also tried with Safe mode, Safe mode with Command Prompt and multiple options but system is auto restarting.....nothing is worked out**.

My system configuration is:

Microsoft Windows XP Professional with Service Pack-3, 32 bit