# irql_not_less_or_equal Disable BIOS Memory options

Tags: windows-xp

When I switch on the PC and system boots/starts with Windows XP Professional OS, I'm able to see the Windows XP logo and with progress bar processing  But after the logo and processing I'm not getting the Welcome or Login screen immediately my PC is getting restarted automatically.

PC On -> Windows XP logo processing screen -> Auto Restarting the PC -> Windows Xp logo processing screen -> Automatically restart

What I tried:

- With Windows XP bootable CD first I tried either Repair option then with Fresh installation also.
- I'm unable to perform Repair or fresh installation of Windows XP Professional too. As soon as I select the Repair or Fresh installation option I'm getting the Blue screen as below.

I'm getting a blue screen with the following information.

Blue screen information:

```
"A problem has been detected and Windows has been shutdown to prevent Damage to your computer IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL
....
...
...
....
Disable BIOS Memory options such as Caching or Shadowing.
....
....
....

STOP: 0x0000000A (0xF000E987, 0x00000002, 0x00000001, 0x808247A4)"
```

I would request if anyone could help me with proper resolution and suitable solution other than Formatting/Clean installation option for the same.

As I tried with Safe mode, Safe mode with Command Prompt and multiple options but system is auto restarting. Nothing is worked out. My system configuration is:

Microsoft Windows XP Professional with Service Pack-3, 32 bit

Comment: Check your BIOS options do you have bios shadowing enabled? It's useless with an NT operating system, so you can disable it.

Comment: @Kyle: In BIOS, this option is disabled by default. hmm... :(

Answer (score 1):

I get this when I have an unstable overclock. Sounds like the processor has gone bad. If you can get into windows for any length of time, run prime95 and see if it goes red. If it does, it'll confirm the processor isn't working properly.

To get over this during an OC, I either drop the bclk or up the vcore voltage. You can try this and see if it helps, but only do that if you know what you are doing because you can burn out your hardware very easily if you don't. I understand you aren't running an overclock but attacking the processor in the same manner may make the system stable.

Run memtest for 24 hours anyway. It won't hurt!

This BSOD can also be driver related, but as you are booting from disc and still getting it, I'd say it's likely the processor.

Comment: "I either drop the bclk or up the vcore voltage." -this is bad advice without knowing what processor he has. Newer processors may use an offset for voltage and newer Intels should not have their BLCK adjusted (use either the blck strap or the multiplier).

Comment: @Simkill, seems my processor, m/b is good. As u mentioned how to run memtest? Please guide me step by step hw to check/attack the processor? My processor is Intel Pentium4

Comment: How to run Prime95

Comment: @Simkill: How can i run Prime95